# How does camber location (xf/c) affect Cl max and stall angle of an airfoil

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

I'm trying to compare 4-digit airfoil and 5-digit airfoil about the effect of camber location towards Cl max and stall angle.

Is it correct if i assume the higher the camber location value the Cl max and stall angle also increase. Also can anyone elaborate on why this is occur?

Answer (score 0):

One can compare all kinds of designs at [airfoiltools.com](http://www.airfoiltools.com).

Higher camber tends to increase the "bending" of the airstream as angle of attack increases and is usually placed near the leading edge for this purpose, resulting in a higher coefficient of lift before stall.

Around the time when biplanes flew at 40 to 100 knots, thick wings with lots of camber proved to have a much wider flight envelope than the thinner wings of the time.  A comparison of the DAE21 cambered to the NACA 0012 symmetrical shows some of the advantages, including an almost 2x increase in Coefficient of Lift to Coefficient of Drag ratio.  In other words, the symmetrical needs to fly at 10 degrees AoA to produce the same lift as the cambered at 5 degrees.  Now the drag comparisons become interesting!

Improvements continued to be made up to the time of the Davis wing.  Only when increased airspeeds caused critical Mach number to become an issue did the age of these wings end, but **retractable slats and Fowler flaps** live on to help high subsonic airliners to slow down to 1/3 their cruising speed and land safely.

Cambered wings, such as the Clark Y, continue to be used with slower recreational aircraft.